# Instagram post's caption is not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to get instagram profile's post with captions, everything is working fine except captions.
It showing : [object Object]

I haven't used any api.

My code:

```
function nFormatter(num){
    if(num >= 1000000000){
      return (num/1000000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/,'') + 'G';
    }
    if(num >= 1000000){
      return (num/1000000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/,'') + 'M';
    }
    if(num >= 1000){
      return (num/1000).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0$/,'') + 'K';
    }
    return num;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://www.instagram.com/bhudiptaakash?__a=1",
    type:'get',
    success:function(response){
      $(".profile-pic").attr('src',response.graphql.user.profile_pic_url);
      posts = response.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges;
      posts_html = '';
      for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
        caption = posts[i].node.edge_media_to_caption;
        likes = posts[i].node.edge_liked_by.count;
        posts_html += '<a href="https://instagram.com/p/'+shortcode+'">: '+caption+';
      }
      $(".posts").html(posts_html);
    }
  });
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: The caption is an object, you need to extract the property you want.

Comment: @Barmar can you please give the solve?

Comment: Use `console.log(caption)` and you should see all the properties.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of `edge_media_to_caption`? I can't find it in the Instagram Graph API doc.

Comment: Nothing Happened

Comment: You didn't see anything in the console?

Comment: Nope My brother

Comment: I haven't use any graph api

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mhsiampro/rkton8Lu
my jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `edge_media_to_caption` property is an object like this:

```
{
    "edges": [{
        "node": {
            "text": "Still alive"
        }
    }]
}
```

You need to loop over the edges and get the `node.text` properties.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
  let caption = posts[i].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges.map(e => e.node.text).join('<br>');
  let likes = posts[i].node.edge_liked_by.count;
  posts_html += '<a href="https://instagram.com/p/' + shortcode + '">: ' + caption + '</a>';
}
```